# Do SFDX projects really need multiple jsconfig.json files?

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, visualstudiocode

I have a project with folders breaking up web components into groups, generally by the role of the user who will be using them, along with a folder for components shared across the app. So my projects looks like this:

```
force-app
|--core
|----classes
|----contentassets
|----lwc
|----...
|--roleA
|----applications
|----lwc
|----...
|--roleB
|----applications
|----lwc
|----...
```

When I launch VS Code, some extension is adding a `jsconfig.json` file to every `lwc` folder. It has the exact same structure each time, allowing experimental decorators, giving the relative path to the TypeScript typings, etc. So, having an OCD aversion to duplicated code, I have two questions:

- Can this be handled by a single `jsconfig.json` in the project's root folder?
- If so, which Salesforce extension is doing this and can I turn it off?

Comment: should probably ask/report this directly on github rather than stackexchange

Answer (score 1):

The file is described [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig). It is used to provide JS language support in VS Code. Technically, you could delete all the duplicates and place a single copy at the project root, as you suggest. However, this may cause improper language support for Aura, Visualforce, and third party scripts in Static Resources. Try it out and see if it works for your project. The extension that creates these files are needed for proper support for Salesforce development and should not be turned off.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I did read what the file was for. I'm not looking to turn the extension off, but looking to see if the extension (which one precisely, there are multiple SFDX extensions) has a setting to turn that specific feature off.

Comment: @Chuck fair enough. It's still suggest moving it up to the root and see if that fixes things for you.

Comment: I actually did that before I posted the question. Things seemed to work. But then the next time I launched VS Code, the files came back. If I can't turn that off, then I'll just stop trying and get back to building code. :) Thanks for the feedback.